# Kernel modules for ReadyNASOS 6.9.X

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to build the pptp (ppp) modules, and I am getting stuck at and error "slhc: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout"

I have been fighting with this for about 1 week now, so I figured it was past time to see if anyone could help. Also, before you say it, yes I have googled for this, but all answers are either out of date or simply don't solve the issue. I am running a ReadyNAS 312.

Here is what I have worked out "should" work...:

```
cd ~/src
wget https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GPL/ReadyNASOS_V6.9.5_WW_src.zip
mkdir ReadyNAS
cd ReadyNAS
7z x ../ReadyNASOS_V6.9.5_WW_src.zip
cd linux-4.4.157-x86_64
make readynas_defconfig
make menuconfig
#Nav to
# Device Drivers-->Network device support
# expand with an M "PPP (point-to-point protocol) support"
# Mark wtih an M:
# PPP MPPE compression (encryption)
# PPP support for async serial ports
# Mark with a * (space bar)
# PPP filtering

make prepare
make modules_prepare

#Since there is no 'Module.symvers'
make
make modules

sudo mkdir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel
sudo mkdir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/lib
sudo mkdir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers
sudo mkdir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net
sudo mkdir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ppp
sudo mkdir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/slip
sudo cp drivers/net/ppp/*.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ppp/
sudo cp drivers/net/slip/*.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/slip/
sudo cp lib/crc-ccitt.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/lib

sudo depmod -a

sudo modprobe ppp_generic
#>modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ppp_generic': Exec format error
tail -n 1 /var/log/syslog
#>Mar  5 09:52:04 nas kernel: [443480.790854] slhc: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I needed to do the following instead of 'make readynas_defconfig'

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-extra
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe configs
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
```